# Why does Int enum as dictionary key, produce different json string than Int as dictionary key?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I try to convert a dictionary, with Int enum

```
enum TypeE: Int, Codable
{
    case note = 1
    case tab
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()

let dictionary0 = [TypeE.note:"VALUE0", TypeE.tab:"VALUE1"]
var data = try encoder.encode(dictionary0)
var string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
// [1,"VALUE0",2,"VALUE1"]
print(string)
```

The produced json string output is

```
[1,"VALUE0",2,"VALUE1"]
```

It looks strange to me. As, the produced json string represents an array.

---

If I tested with

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

let dictionary1 = [1:"VALUE0", 2:"VALUE1"]
var data = try encoder.encode(dictionary1)
var string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
// {"1":"VALUE0","2":"VALUE1"}
print(string)
```

The produced json string output is

```
{"1":"VALUE0","2":"VALUE1"}
```

It seems like if I use Int enum as dictionary key, the produced json string will become representation of array?

Is there any mistake in my code, or my expectation is incorrect?

Comment: JSON Dict keys needs to be a String. That's strange, but I guess the encoder tried to fixed it transforming it into an Array, but I would have expected an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code of [Codable](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L5550) provides explanation for this behavior. If the key isn't a `String` or an `Int`, the resulting type is an `Array`:

```
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    if Key.self == String.self {
      // Since the keys are already Strings, we can use them as keys directly.
      ...
    } else if Key.self == Int.self {
      // Since the keys are already Ints, we can use them as keys directly.
      ...
    } else {
      // Keys are Encodable but not Strings or Ints, so we cannot arbitrarily
      // convert to keys. We can encode as an array of alternating key-value
      // pairs, though.
      var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
      for (key, value) in self {
        try container.encode(key)
        try container.encode(value)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great pointer. But, I still do not understand, why they can't just use the `rawValue` of enum, which is `Int`? If you understand why, do you mind to explain?

Comment: I'm assuming that the person who wrote the implementation decided to ignore the case where the `Key` is `RawRepresentable` and `Key.RawValue == Int` (or `String)`. Would need insight from someone from the Swift team.

Comment: On a more general note - complex `Codable` objects can't become keys, because this would not be a valid json object: `{ {"complex_obj": 1}: "value" }`

Answer (score 0):

I made an extension for your case may be useful:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == TypeE.RawValue, Value == String {
    
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (TypeE, String)...) {
        var headers: [TypeE.RawValue: String] = [:]
        for pair in elements {
            headers[pair.0.rawValue] = pair.1
        }
        
        self = headers
    }
    
    subscript(typeE t: TypeE) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[t.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            self[t.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var dic2 = Dictionary<TypeE.RawValue, String>.init(dictionaryLiteral: (TypeE.note,"Str"), (TypeE.tab,"Str2"))
```

add new key/Value:

```
dic2[typeE: TypeE.thirdCase] = "Str3"
```

O/P:
[image]

and get specific key:

[image]