# What is wrong with my enum decoding in Swift?

Tags: swift, decodable

I just tried this:

```
let test = "{ \"de\": \"Bisasam\", \"en\": \"Bulbasaur\" }"
let data = test.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: String].self, from: data)
    print("") // breakpoint here works
} catch {
    print("")
}
```

This works fine, however when I try to do this instead:

```
enum Lg: String, CaseIterable, Decodable {
    case deutsch = "de"
    case english = "en"
}

let test = "{ \"de\": \"Bisasam\", \"en\": \"Bulbasaur\" }"
let data = test.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Lg: String].self, from: data)
    print("")
} catch {
    print("") // breakpoint here
}
```

With this error:

> ▿ DecodingError
> ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
>
> - .0 : Swift.Array
>   ▿ .1 : Context
>
>   - codingPath : 0 elements
>   - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."
>   - underlyingError : nil

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: See [Why does Int enum as dictionary key, produce different json string than Int as dictionary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114149/why-does-int-enum-as-dictionary-key-produce-different-json-string-than-int-as-d) for relevant information about JSON and enum keys.

Comment: Here is a nice solution to your issue.... https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/codable-swift-dictionaries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a non-`String` non-`Int` type as the dictionary key, `Dictionary`'s `Decodable` implementation expects an array of key value pairs, i.e.:

```
["de", "foo", "en": "bar"]
```

This decodes to `[.deutsch: "foo", .english: "bar"]`.

JSON keys can only be strings after all, and the `Decodable` implementation doesn't know how to convert a random `Decodable` value into a string. It could have been made to check for `RawRepresentable` with `RawValue == String`, but it wasn't.

One thing that it does check for though, is [`CodingKeyRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkeyrepresentable), if you just conform `Lg` to that, then you can decode a JSON dictionary correctly.

> Conforming a type to `CodingKeyRepresentable` lets you opt in to encoding and decoding `Dictionary` values keyed by the conforming type to and from a keyed container, rather than encoding and decoding the dictionary as an unkeyed container of alternating key-value pairs.

```
extension Lg: CodingKeyRepresentable, CodingKey {
    init?<T>(codingKey: T) where T : CodingKey {
        self.init(rawValue: codingKey.stringValue)
    }
    
    var codingKey: CodingKey {
        self
    }
}
```

Note that I also conformed it to `CodingKey` to make it easier to write the `codingKey` property required by `CodingKeyRepresentable`.